# Security practices with ngrok?

Tags: network, tunneling

I know many developers use a tunnelling software called [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), yet many don't know how it works or what it's doing. An example of its use is in [testing webhooks on a development server](https://jameschambers.co.uk/rails-6-webhook-ngrok-testing)

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36552950/5783745) question which indicates it has some strong usage and big companies use it.

I wonder what is it doing to the computer (e.g. opening ports which could open attack vectors?), and how can it be used safely/responsibly?

Comment: You're essentially making reverse tunnels to make holes in your firewall and giving the keys to an outer entity. I see no valid reason for a large company to use it.

Comment: @Ginnungagap what ability/ies does it give the outer entity? Could someone snoop on just the app being tested, or your whole computer?

Comment: It essentially bypasses the firewall to open a port on your local machine (that's pretty much the finality of it) if it happens that you have an app listening on it that's OK (but then why not open the port in your firewall), but encouraging ngrok's use in a company is basically throwing away any network policy you have.